# USSD, How to authenticate ussd sessions

Tags: gsm, smpp, ussd

I am making an application to be used as a service by telephones over GSM network.
The app will be running in a web server and will be connected by web service to GSM application.

Specifically, the service will use USSD mobile protocol to talk to end user phones and I need a way to authenticate and persist user sessions so that ussd requests in the same sessions only authenticate once.

One solution is to use the built-in sim PUK mechanism to authenticate the requests, but I don't know/understand how to trigger this form of authentication

Comment: Which protocol are you using toward GSM network, smpp, ss7 map...?
Are you talking about network initiate USSD ?

Comment: @Marvin You mean protocol to talk to ussd gateway. it is Http.

Comment: Why do you need authentication ? When you initiate NI USSD toward user, you probably decide whether the call is onetime or dialog, in that case you must get back session id from USSD server upon first call.
Which USSD vendor do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

you can store that session_id on server cache, as a static hashmap variable, with unique key
After finish transaction, you have to remove value by key

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).